# Issue in displaying events in Fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, asp.net-ajax

Hi I am trying to implement FullCalendar.js with Asp.Net MVC. I am abl to show empty calendar but my events are not getting loaded in the Calendar.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: "/Matter/GetMatterEventsSummary",
                data: data,

                datatype: "Json",

                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (doc) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
                    var events = [];
                    $(doc).find('[object Object],[object Object]').each(function () {
                        debugger;
                    events.push({

                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                        });
                   // });
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                  //  callback(events);
                }

            });
```

it comes to success method and it has two events in it . but dont know why theseevents are not loaded into FullCalendar and also after this Calendar is not comingg automatically.
I guess it is not going in events.push. When I do hover on doc it shows "[object Object],[object Object]"  and in this it has two records on [0] and [1].

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' )
```

after your events have been pulled.

Also, make sure to use the code from the official documentation properly. Try the following (untested):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: "/Matter/GetMatterEventsSummary",
        data: data,
        datatype: "Json",
        contentType: "application/json",,
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

If you now want to refetch your events, call :

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

where necessary.

EDIT:
Since your are actually pulling data from a JSON feed, the following code may even be enough:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/Matter/GetMatterEventsSummary'
});
```

Check the documentation [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/):

EDIT2:

To dynamically modify the request you send to the backend (depending on a dropdown or something else), may be achieved as follows:

```
 var myValue = 10;

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/Matter/GetMatterEventsSummary',
    data: function() { // a function that returns an object
        return {
            dynamic_value: myValue
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get the events on the Calendar with the edited answer but still facing the issue as when the page is first loading I am getting nothing and if I click on the arrow I will get the data.

Comment: Also I want to show the current month activities in the Calendar, do I need to pass dates in this and if yes then how will month will change on click of arrow.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, have you tried calling 'refetchEvents' (after you calendar has been loaded), as I described above? Regarding your second comment, I'm not exactly sure if I understand you correctly. As written in the documentation (link in my answer), fullcalendar automatically send start and end date like (.../Matter/GetMatterEventsSummary/start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12) to the backend. Every time you click on the arrow, an new request will be sent to the backend with adjusted start/end dates. In the backend you have to read out those values and return the appropriate events.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried the 'refetchEvents' (after the calendar has been loaded) but didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you also tell me how can I change the data of Calendar on dropdown change event, I am able to get the data according to changed value of dropdown but how can I set this value on the success event.

Comment: Please check if your are actually receiving a request in the backend when calling 'refetchEvents'. I also updated the answer to show you how you can dynamically send the value from a dropdown or anything else with your request. However, comments should actually not be used for asking new and/or different questions than your initial one. Without any sample code, it is also difficult to find the exact issue.